# Run .NET executable in Ubuntu (or wine)

Tags: ubuntu, .net-framework, wine

I tried running a .NET executable in wine, but it is not opening up. The particular executable refers to some .NET dlls (assemblies) located at the same place as the exe. Is there any way to run it in wine or by using some other method?

P.S The application uses Google Data API  to fetch data from google docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), an open source cross-platform implementation of the .NET framework.

You can install mono by simply issuing:

```
sudo apt-get install mono
```

Afterwards, you can run the .NET executable by passing it into mono, like so:

```
mono SomeApplication.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Mono is the platform to run .net apps in linux/ubuntu. But it needs to be supported by the developer. So far I know, the executables are different in mono. So, you cannot run the app directly in mono. If you have the source code, then you can try to migrate it to mono with [MOMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA). If you don't have the source, the you can consult the developer.

I am not a WINE user. But I think .net framework should also be installed in WINE to run a .net app. Maybe [*this*](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1140452.htm) link will help.

Comment: First, .NET executables should be executable directly by Mono without recompilation. Second, MOMA is a migration *analyzer* only. Third, if you talk about Wine it's always nice [to link to the appdb entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586), because *everything* in the end ends up there on information needed.

Answer (score -3):

Try this...

```
 $ ­wget http://winetricks.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/winetricks

 $ bash winetricks dotnet40
```

After that you can running .net framework without any problem.

Thanks..